Facebook Graph API adcreatives
enter image description here
I use /adcreatives to create such a post on the page. But to appear on the page, it requires payment setup.
I want to create a post on the page with a like page button like the picture. no need to advertise, can anyone help me?

I could be wrong, but your question seems not suitable for SO. I suggest that you take the [tour] and read [ask].
